# C# WPF: Getting Custom Binding Error (Converter Property Unknown) After Restoring Project from SourceSafe

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, compiler-errors, markup

I have been working on this C# project for months now and it's always had a custom binding class just to make some of the properties a bit quicker:

```
namespace AutoLogic_GT
{
    public class BindingEx : Binding
    {
        public BindingEx()
        {
            IsAsync = true;
        }
    }

    public class BindingEx2Way : Binding
    {
        public BindingEx2Way()
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        }
    }

    public class BindingExReadOnly : Binding
    {
        public BindingExReadOnly()
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it in my XAML code using:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BoolValueConverter x:Key="boolConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource BasicCheckBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{local:BindingEx Path=DsBuyer.FirstTimeBuyer, TargetNullValue=False, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}" />
```

And the converter code is straightforward as well:

```
public sealed class BoolValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToBool();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToBool();
    }
}
```

It's been working fine forever, and even on my build machine, it still works fine but just yesterday I had to replace my hard drive and download all of the latest source code from TFS and everything looks good and right, all the code is identical to the build server but on my development server, I can't compile the code. I keep getting the error:

> Error     Unknown property 'Converter' for type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension. Line 39 Position 114.

I get that same error for every one that is calling an additional property besides just Path.

i.e. -

> Error     Unknown property 'FallbackValue' for type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension.

and

> Error     Unknown property 'TargetNullValue' for type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension.

Etc...

I had to of course re-install Visual Studio 2017 CE and I am back on the same version I was on prior to the HDD replacement because I always kept VS up to date but it seems like something else might be missing or out of date or perhaps a mismatched or outdated NuGet compiler package or something because it otherwise doesn't make sense that the code itself is bad when it's been working for months before and still continues to work and compile fine on the build machine.

Anyone know what I can check that might get me going on this? The only alternative is to go back through all of the code and get rid of the custom binding (if that's even the true cause) but that will take days to do because there's thousands of bindings in this project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. As suspected, it wasn't the problem as described at all. In my case, it turned out that one of the forms were referencing an assembly (PresentationFramework.Classic) that wasn't added to the project for some reason and that caused the propagating set of errors due to the fact that it couldn't compile from top-down.

```
 xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Classic"
```

Pain in the butt WPF debugging can be sometimes.